# Curved path with variables in Snap SVG

Tags: snap.svg

I am trying to make a **curved path** in **snap svg** that uses **variables** instead of numbers.

I have this basic example working:

```
var newpath = s.path("M100 200 C100 100 250 100 250 200 S400 300 400 200");
newpath.attr({
   stroke: "#FFFFFF",
   strokeWidth: 1
});
```

But when I insert a variable then the line diappears:

```
var newpath = s.path("centerx 200 C100 100 250 100 250 200 S400 300 400 200");
newpath.attr({
   stroke: "#FFFFFF",
   strokeWidth: 1
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable centerx should not be contained within the quotation marks.

```
var newpath = s.path(centerx + " 200 C100 100 250 100 250 200 S400 300 400 200");
newpath.attr({
   stroke: "#FFFFFF",
   strokeWidth: 1
});
```

Comment: It depends what centerx is. You may mean something like "M" + centerx + " 200.... If you can post the code you currently are testing now, it will probably be straightforward.